# Why g++ compiling with -ggdb option step-ups size of binary file?

Tags: gdb, g++

I was compiled a product source code with g++ compiler and provided option -ggdb to gain access to gdb debugging. but it was taking some bit more files size than file which compiled without -ggdb. please explain me what -ggdb includes in actual binary? ie., binary compiled without -ggdb option.

Comment: When you add the `-g` option (or any of its "sub" options like `-ggdb`) the compiler and linker adds *all* the debug information needed. All symbol names, line-number information (including where symbols were defined/declared), links to the source (but not the source itself), and probably a lot more.

Answer (score 0):

> please explain me what -ggdb includes in actual binary?

Look at the output from `readelf -WS a.out` for the two binaries.

You will discover that GCC added a few large `.debug_*` sections, which contain information needed by the debugger to map code addresses in your binary to source file and line, data addresses to variable names, etc. etc.